# Pandas-Python : How do you write new lines in Pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to save a list of `JSON` output from `API's GET requests` into `CSV` file using `Pandas` but below codes only generates single entry, it doesn't create new lines.

**sample JSON output** :

```
ID : 27980
Title : ELSVIOS 6 Colors Boho Split Long <font><b>Dress</b></font> Fashion Women O-Neck Maxi <font><b>Dress</b></font> Summer Short Sleeve Solid <font><b>Dress</b></font> With Belt Vestidos XS-3XL32815751265US
Price : $10.32US 
Sale Price :$10.32
```

---

```
for resultsget in getlistproductsx:
                    producturls = resultsget['productTitle']
                    productids = resultsget['productId']
                    originalprices = resultsget['originalPrice']
                    saleprices = resultsget['salePrice']
                    print(producturls + str(productids) + originalprices + saleprices)
                    raw_data = {'product_title': [producturls],
                            'product_id': [productids],
                            'original_price': [originalprices],
                            'sale_price': [saleprices]}
                    df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['product_title', 'product_id', 'original_price', 'sale_price'])
                    df.to_csv('example2.csv')
```

Comment: Seems, you just override file, and create new DataFrame - and not appending it.

Comment: kosist I'm new to this, could you show me how ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As kosist said, you're overwriting your CSV File.

Create a second DataFrame to which you will append the data you imported in the loop.

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['product_title', 'product_id', 'original_price', 'sale_price']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

for resultsget in getlistproductsx:
    producturls = resultsget['productTitle']
    productids = resultsget['productId']
    originalprices = resultsget['originalPrice']
    saleprices = resultsget['salePrice']

    print(producturls + str(productids) + originalprices + saleprices)
    raw_data = {'product_title': [producturls],
                'product_id': [productids],
                'original_price': [originalprices],
                'sale_price': [saleprices]}

    # create second DataFrame to which the data is added
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=cols)
    # append the newly created DataFrame to the one keeping the data
    df  = df.append(df2)

# then write the DataFrame to csv
df.to_csv('csv.csv')
```

Comment: vnthn your code only write the same output over and over again

Comment: @ReezalAl-Qadiri you were right, I fixed it. Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to load all your lines into a pandas `DataFrame` and after that do `to_csv` like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(getlistproductsx)
df.to_csv('csv.csv')
```